# What is wrong with my code? It says segmentation fault

Tags: c

What I am trying to do is, take the message from the user input and reverse the string. So, I am using 2 pointers, one is pointing at the first element of the message array and the other is pointing to the last element. And then I am doing the swap until the two pointers meet.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
void reverse(char* message);
    int main()
    {
        char message[100];

        printf("Enter a message: ");
        scanf("%s",message);
        printf("\nok");
        reverse(message);
        printf("ok \n");
        printf("%s",message);

        return 0;
    }

    void reverse(char* message){

        char* p = message;
        char* temp = message;
        char* q = (message + (strlen(message)); // pointing to the last element before 
                                             // null character

        printf("\ncoming");
        while( p != q){

                                  // why am I getting a segmentation fault? whats happening?
            *p = *q;
            *q = *temp;

            p++;
            q--;
            temp = p;  

        }// while loop
    }// reverse
```

Comment: Look closely at how you swap the characters. Also, `s + strlen(s)` does not point to the last character before the null teminator, as the comment claims. It points right at the null terminator.

Comment: With both `p++` and `q--` the while test `p != q` can be always true (infinite loop). Can you see in which case this can occur (suppose p and q points 2 consecutive characters, what will occur after `p++` and `q--` ?  
What will happen if the `while` loop never finishes (where are going `p` and `q`) ?
Note also that the swap is not correct. You need a `temp` variable of type `char`.

Comment: Think of this string `xy`. Here your `p` will never equal to `q`, and the loop will not stop, that's what caused the segmentation fault.

Comment: I fixed the while loop condition. Now i gave while(p < q) but the swapping isnt happening, can anyone explain why?

Comment: When compiling, always enable the warnings, then fix those warnings.  ( for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=gnu11` )  Note: other compilers use different options to produce the same results.

Comment: OT:  regarding: `scanf("%s",message);`  1) When using the `%s` and/or the `%[...]` format specifiers, always include a MAX CHARACTERS modifier that is 1 less than the length of the input buffer, because these format specifiers always append a NUL byte to the input.  This avoid any buffer overflow and the resulting undefined behavior  2) always check the returned value (not the parameter values) to assure the operation was successful.  Note: these functions return the number of successful format conversion operations (any other returned value indicates an error occurred

Comment: regarding: `char* q = (message + (strlen(message));`  This is missing a closing paren just before the `;`

Answer (score 1):

This line

```
char* q = (message + (strlen(message));
```

Does it point to the last character.

Consider a message of one character - `strlen(message)` will by one. But the first character would be `char * q = message`

So the line should read

```
char* q = (message + strlen(message) - 1;
```

Also the swap is a be awry

Try

```
char temp;
```

Instead then instead of

```
*p = *q; 
*q = *temp;
p++;
q--;
temp = p;
```

Use

```
temp = *p;  // We got the temp
*p = *q;    // Old p is safe - it is now temp.
*q = temp;

p++;
q++;
```

With this code the null character is not reversed! Hence in the right place!

Finalluy,

```
while( p != q){
```

Should be

```
while( p < q){
```

Answer (score 0):

regarding:

```
p++;
q--;
```

After the above statements, the pointers can have passed each other.  Then the loop keeps running until the seg. fault occurs

Answer (score 0):

*I fixed the while loop condition. Now i gave while(p < q) but the swapping isnt happening, can anyone explain why?*

Both pointers `p` and `temp` are pointing at `message`:
`char* p = message;`
`char* temp = message;`

When `*p = *q;` is executed in the while loop, the character pointed by "p" **and the character pointed by "temp"**, get updated with the character at "q" (because of the above declarations).
The next line `*q = *temp;` is essentially copying the newly updated character("*q") back to "q".

In addition, as pointed out by "M Oehm", the line
`message + strlen(message)`, points at the NULL character, instead of the last character before NULL.

Also note the comment posted by "user3629249" regarding the missing parentheses.

Correcting these your code should look like...

```
void reverse(char* message){

    char* p = message;
    char* temp = message;
    char* q = (message + strlen(message)-1); // pointing to the last element 
    char c; //to store the value of "temp"                          

    printf("\ncoming");
    while( p < q){

        c = *temp;              
        *p = *q;
        *q = c;

        p++;
        q--;
        temp = p;  

    }// while loop
}// reverse
```

Having said this, since "C" passes parameters by value, you could implement the same function, like so....

```
void reverse(char* message){

    char* q = (message + strlen(message)-1);
    char c;                                     
    while( message < q){
        c = *message;
        *message = *q;
        *q = c;
        message++;
        q--;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

A [*segmentation fault*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segmentation_fault) is caused by a program trying to read or write an illegal memory location. With both `p++` and `q--` the `while (p != q)` can be always true, for instance if `p` and `q` point at 2 consecutive characters. Check this approach for string reversing:

```
#include <string.h>

void reverse(char *str)
{
    //skip null string
    if (str == 0)
    {
        return;
    }

    // skip empty string
    if (*str == 0)
    {
        return;
    }

    // get range
    char *start = str;
    char *end = start + strlen(str) - 1; // -1 for the end \0
    char temp;

    // reverse 
    while (end > start)
    {
        // swap chars
        temp = *start;
        *start = *end;
        *end = temp;

        // move to next position
        ++start;
        --end;
    }
}


int main(void)
{
    char s1[] = "Stack Overflow is GREAT!";
    reverse(s1);
    printf("%s\n", s1);

    return 0;
}
```